# Spring Boot run command line and terminate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a large Spring Boot monolithic Web Application project. This application is packaged as an executable JAR and serves all kinds of JSON REST endpoints.

**Now, I sometimes want to run a piece of Java code to process or import a large file, or clean up certain database tables from the command line.**

What would be good way to do this with Spring Boot?

I first looked into `CommandLineRunner` interface but this seems to serve a completely different use case. This is executed always when running the Spring Boot application, followed by starting the main application.

I would like to have this functionality in the same application as the main web app for various reasons:

- Reuse same application configuration (DB credentials, external config files, etc.)
- Reuse application context
- Shared application logic and code
- Difficult to split into smaller (micro) services

Comment: Are you specifically talking about Database interactions e.g. loading of data, changing schemas, etc?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe it can be anything, really. The main takeaway is that you definitely don't want to run it alongside normal application startup (like you might want to do with updating DB schemas)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse the same jar, you could use a combination of `Profiles` and `CommandLineRunners`.

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("import")
    public CommandLineRunner import() {
        // ...
    } 

    @Bean
    @Profile("dbClean")
    public CommandLineRunner dbClean() {
        // ...
    } 

}
```

Then, when you run the jar, pass the desired profile as argument.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dbClean yourJar.jar
```

In this way, your command line runners are executed only when the profile matches.

Comment: And will this only execute the CommandLineRunner and then terminate? Or will it still execute the main web application as it normally does?

Comment: By default it will execute the web app, but you can manually terminate the application at the end of the command line runner.

Comment: Since you need the application context to start up, for example for db operations.